# KnockoutJS how to programmatically set value in dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I forked the KnockoutJS cart editor example from the tutorials at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/o38pzw18/3/) and only changed

```
self.category = ko.observable();
```

to

```
self.category = ko.observable('Planes');
```

Why can't I programmatically set the value of the Category dropdown to default to Planes? I thought you could set this value and the ko binding automatically refreshed the dropdown with the new value? Is it not responding because it's subscribed to or do I need to set this a different way?

--Steve

Comment: do `self.category('Planes')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bound to a collection of strings. It happens to display as a string because of this part of the binding: `optionsText: "name"`. To set which value it's bound to you need to set it to the object itself.

The objects themselves are in an array called `sampleProductCategories` which, rather confusingly, are actually included from a separate file in that fiddle:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/sampleProductCategories.js

So to set it to planes, you need to set it to an object from that array:

```
self.category = ko.observable(sampleProductCategories[2]);
```

It happens to be the third entry.

http://jsfiddle.net/o38pzw18/4/

Of course, if you don't want to manually find the indexes of each item, you could do something like this:

```
var planes = sampleProductCategories.filter(function(item) {
    return item.name = "Planes";
})[0];
self.category = ko.observable(planes);
```

Comment: fantastic description - I had seen that done but didn't know why, and didn't know if it was needed.